# permutation on a circle within some distance

Tags: combinatorics

Assuming $n$ children sitting around a round table. For example, 7 children.

At the second time they changed seats, so this is a permutation $\omega$.

Each child's new seat and previous seat define a distance, if the permutation is $6 1 2 5 3 4 0$
, so now the child last round took seat #$0$ is now seating at #$6$, so he moved $1$ distance, or $d(0)=1$.

Call the biggest distance of all the children the distance of the circle permutation. For example the distance of all the children are $1,0,0,1,1,2,1$, so the $d(\omega) = \max_i d(i) = 2$.

Now the questions is, for $n$ children, if the distance shall be no more than $k$, how many permutations $N(n,k)$ are there?

Of course $\forall n$, $N(n,0)=1$, i.e. no one moves.

If $k=1$ it's also simple, $N(n,1) = F(n+1)+F(n-1)+2$, here $F(n)$ is the Fibonacci numbers starting with $F(0)=0$, and $F(1)=1$.
for example if $n=10$, then $N(10,1)=135$.

But when $k\ge 2$ it's turns quite complex I couldn't find a nice solution. For example by programming it shows $N(10,2) = 6208$ but I couldn't find a close form or recursive form for it.

Is there a way to compute it? Or, the simple case, is there a close or recursive form for $N(n,2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a(n)= N(n, 2)$. The sequence $a(n)$ is available on the OEIS as [A000804](https://oeis.org/A000804), which includes many references.

An interesting reference there is ["Permutations with Restricted Displacement"](https://doi.org/10.1137/0608029), in which they also look at these numbers as the number of permutations with restrictions. They do not look at permutations where elements can only move 2 in both directions, but they look at permutations where elements can move at most 4 to the right, which is the same number. (can you think of the bijection to prove that?)

In the notation of that paper, you are looking at $a(n, 5)$. $a(n, 4)$ is the last one for which they provide the recurrence relation, as that is the last simple one. For $a(n, 5), a(n, 6), a(n, 7), a(n, 8)$ and $a(n, 9)$ they refer to [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(69)80058-X). For each $k$ you are looking for $N(n, k) = a(n, 2k+1)$.

The recursive formula for $N(n, 2) = a(n, 5) = a(n)$ presented there (formula 1.3) can be written as

$$
\begin{aligned}
a(n) &= 2a(n-1) + 2a(n-2)-2a(n-4)\\
&-8a(n-5) -6a(n-6)- 2a(n-7)\\
&+ 2a(n-9) + a(n-10) + 24
\end{aligned}
$$

This recursion relation is valid for $n \geq 15$. For $n \leq 5$, we simply have $a(n) = n!$. This leaves the values for $n = 6, \cdots, 14$ to be precomputed (or you can find them [here](https://oeis.org/A000804/b000804.txt)).

[This python snippet](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxlkt1qxCAQhe99irmMLQsa419poA9SKJLGVsjqYpP3r-naNHbmQjzM5zkj6nO6gt_itKa0fEG43lJeYcnb2-Smz5mQl2PfUfI-e3BdpE8ESgUPEZ6B3dVeeV63HIGd2iNI1PeuxOXglmL1h44jKIT2SjaERoTUtiEMIvh_E4tjtBENwvGtVM9My3AcJSxrx-E9ggQXQreQQJBm1rRT8wHHKS6HO_V7kYfyPnABTuHxED3dlyqGXZgqJH09PEtdQNWGOh_RZzO7ixrCfhoDIT5lCBAiZBc_5o4zVv_ILYe4dq4LlH4DL1yPow==&lang=python&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) uses that recursion to compute the first 100 values of $a(n)$ instantly.

The recursions for $N(n, 3) = a(n, 7)$ and $N(n, 4) = a(n, 9)$ are also available there but the formulas get huge. Precomputed values are also available on the OEIS under [A008305](https://oeis.org/A008305).